# Unable to create or delete specific page in Mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki

I get this error for a specific page (MW 1.31) without following a history link.

```
The revision #0 of the page named "x" does not exist.

This is usually caused by following an outdated history link to a page that has been deleted. Details can be found in the deletion log.
```

Deleting is not possible. When I try to edit and save, I get the same error and/or

```
Someone else has changed this page since you started editing it. The upper text area contains the page text as it currently exists. Your changes are shown in the lower text area. You will have to merge your changes into the existing text. Only the text in the upper text area will be saved when you press "Save changes".
```

The page in pages table:
https://ibb.co/tw6tydF

And in revisions table:
https://ibb.co/RDGbmnc

Would deleting those entries be a solution or there may be some other relevant instance in the dB?

Comment: are you sure that ```page_title``` in that table is correct? It looks a bit weird to me

Comment: Yes, it is correct, it has to do with how UTF-8 may appear on dB content.